# Multiple "not more than"-style offenses in sentencing guidelines

Tags: united-states, federal-courts

Federal sentencing guidelines tend to use 'not more than' x amount of time in what I assume is a reverse mandatory minimum, disallowing a judge from 'throwing the book' at the offender. However, some crimes lend themselves to a more....serial nature. Say, when a certain politician obstructs justice dozens of times before he's arrested. Do these 'not more than' sentencing guidelines mean that the multiple individual charges can't be served concurrently? Or is it just referring to a maximum sentence for one instance of the crime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each separate conviction of a separate crime carries its own separate penalty.

Three convictions leads to three separate sentences.

It is up to a judge's discretion to say if the sentences should be imposed concurrently or consecutively.